# How to apply structure in the subset of MATLAB table?

Tags: matlab

I have historical data in matlab table from 1990 to 2016. The table has 5 variables/columns including the Date such as, var1=Date, var2=A, var3=B, var4=C, and var5=D.

Let us call this matlab table as Data.

I'd like to create another matlab table of in-sample or subset from DataAll and put them into matlab structure. There should be only 2 variables on each in-sample such as Date and A. My goal is, my structure will comprised of 
field1 = Data1(1990-2000), field2 = Data2(1990-2001), field3 = Data3(1990-2002), field4 = Data4(1990-2003), field5 = Data5(1990-2004), field6 = Data6(1990-2005), field7 = Data7(1990-2006), field8 = Data8(1990-2007), field9 = Data9(1990-2008), field10 = Data10(1990-2009), field11 = Data11(1990-2010), field12 = Data12(1990-2011), field13 = Data13(1990-2012), field14 = Data14(1990-2013), field15 = Data15(1990-2014), and field16 = Data16(1990-2015)

Many thanks.

I created a code, however it is very lengthy and I would like to shorten it using for loop. May I know how it is?

---

```
% In-sample 1990-2000
rows00 = year(Data.Date)<2001;
vars00 = {'Date','A'};
D00 = Data(rows00,vars00);

% In-sample 1990-2001
rows01 = year(Data.Date)<2002;
vars01 = {'Date','A'};
D01 = Data(rows01,vars01);

% In-sample 1990-2002
rows02 = year(Data.Date)<2003;
vars02 = {'Date','A'};
D02 = Data(rows02,vars02);

% In-sample 1990-2003
rows03 = year(Data.Date)<2004;
vars03 = {'Date','A'};
D03 = Data(rows03,vars03);

% In-sample 1990-2004
rows04 = year(Data.Date)<2005;
vars04 = {'Date','A'};
D04 = Data(rows04,vars04);

% In-sample 1990-2005
rows05 = year(Data.Date)<2006;
vars05 = {'Date','A'};
D05 = Data(rows05,vars05);

% In-sample 1990-2006
rows06 = year(Data.Date)<2007;
vars06 = {'Date','A'};
D06 = Data(rows06,vars06);

% In-sample 1990-2007
rows07 = year(Data.Date)<2008;
vars07 = {'Date','A'};
D07 = Data(rows07,vars07);

% In-sample 1990-2008
rows08 = year(Data.Date)<2009;
vars08 = {'Date','A'};
D08 = Data(rows08,vars08);

% In-sample 1990-2009
rows09 = year(Data.Date)<2010;
vars09 = {'Date','A'};
D09 = Data(rows09,vars09);

% In-sample 1990-2010
rows10 = year(Data.Date)<2011;
vars10 = {'Date','A'};
D10 = Data(rows10,vars10);

% In-sample 1990-2011
rows11 = year(Data.Date)<2012;
vars11 = {'Date','A'};
D11 = Data(rows11,vars11);

% In-sample 1990-2012
rows12 = year(Data.Date)<2013;
vars12 = {'Date','A'};
D12 = Data(rows12,vars12);

% In-sample 1990-2013
rows13 = year(Data.Date)<2014;
vars13 = {'Date','A'};
D13 = Data(rows13,vars13);

% In-sample 1990-2014
rows14 = year(Data.Date)<2015;
vars14 = {'Date','A'};
D14 = Data(rows14,vars14);

% In-sample 1990-2015
rows15 = year(Data.Date)<2016;
vars15 = {'Date','A'};
D15 = Data(rows15,vars15);

field1 = 'Y1990_2000'; 
field2 = 'Y1990_2001'; 
field3 = 'Y1990_2002'; 
field4 = 'Y1990_2003'; 
field5 = 'Y1990_2004'; 
field6 = 'Y1990_2005'; 
field7 = 'Y1990_2006'; 
field8 = 'Y1990_2007'; 
field9 = 'Y1990_2008'; 
field10 = 'Y1990_2009'; 
field11 = 'Y1990_2010'; 
field12 = 'Y1990_2011'; 
field13 = 'Y1990_2012'; 
field14 = 'Y1990_2013'; 
field15 = 'Y1990_2014'; 
field16 = 'Y1990_2015'; 

Insample = struct(field1,D00,field2,D01,field3,D02,field4,D03,field5,D04,...
field6,D05,field7,D06,field8,D07,field9,D08,field10,D09,field11,D10,...
field12,D11,field13,D12,field14,D13,field15,D14,field16,D15);
```

Comment: I made a code. However, it is very lengthy and I would like to shorten it using for loop. May I ask how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the final structure as final

```
final = cell(2,1,16); % 2*1 cell for 16 Data set
```

Now access each cell separately and you can also fed table in them, it would be simply as accessing any 3D matrix but you will have to convert the input into cell element before feeding as:

```
var2 = [1,2;3,4]; % Assume var2 for Data1 to be fed in field4
% Adding var2 for Data1 in field4
final(1,2,4) = mat2cell(var2,size(var2,1),size(var2,2));
```

you can also refer to `mat2cell(I,dim1,dim2)` syntax, and also you will have to convert to number when using the data for some statistics.